# How to create a pipeline process in DDD?

Tags: python, domain-driven-design, microservices, bounded-contexts

I've some difficulties in defining pipeline process using DDD. My scenario is the following:

There are 3 bounded contexts:

- patient data manager: responsible to retrieve and manager the entire patient's data, like mrna, mirna, dna methylation, and so on.
- annotation data management: that's annotation about gene, mirna, proteins and so on.
- analyzer: that's a specfic analyzer that uses some patient's data and extracts some usefull information about that. Further, The user can create a pipeline and create puglins, defining some additional steps to process using patient's data. Each step is unique and does just one job, like this:

  pipeline1: task1 -> task2 -> task3 -> task4
  pipeline2: task1 -> task3 -> task5 -> task6

Each task can generate some data, because of this, the task has to manager data, reading and writing data.

I'd like to reduce coupling between the tasks and taks with patient data manager context.

For exemple: task1 must get data in the patient data manager, because of amount of data. the task1 gets some data, process it and then get more data and process again. This process result some data that task1 saves.

Then, the next task in the pipeline is task3. Task3 get the entire data from the task1. The taks3 process the data, resulting another data. The task 3 saves them. The pipeline has finished.

Note the pipeline is configured before running and also each task needs some data to work and generates some data.

I thought of using command pattern tho gets data in the patient data manager context. About the pipeline, it has factories to define and configure pipeline and each task has a command for getting data to process and command for saving its data.

I know that a tightly coupling because the commands. I thought of using choreography pattern using message, however that's really difficult to implement because of pipeline and the amount of data in the patient data manager and the amount of data each task results.

That's okay to do it? There is another better solution?

The code is in python.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I hope this video helps https://youtu.be/9FC_0WMmgKk

Answer (score 1):

DDD doesn't conflict with pipelines in any way. The question is somewhat hypothetical but I'll try to answer it the best I could. Technically, you can just have a generic task interface that does the domain specific task. For instance, see the below boilerplate.

```
class DomainTask1:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def run(self):
        # do something

class DomainTask2:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def run(self):
        # do something else

def run_pipeline(pipeline):
    for task in pipeline:
        task.run()

pipeline = [
    DomainTask1(),
    DomainTask2()
]

run_pipeline(pipeline)
```